# Log user status (archlinux)

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, logs, syslog

I'd like to write a code that restricts myself from accessing the laptop for too long. To do that, I have to have access to user's active time.

Currently, I use `ac` (a part of GNU accounting utils) to see how long a user has been logged in. However, when a user is suspended by `$ systemctl suspend`, the logger keeps ticking.

#### Question

1. How to see how long a user is **active**?
2. A user might be suspended, hibernated, .. in other status etc. Is there a comprehend program that keeps track of all these?